# Requiring to move to older Crystal reports version to work with reports

Tags: asp.net, wpf, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am running version 13.0.24  of crystal reports but have to revert to an older version to print out reports. How can I update the compatibility for my app to include newer CR versions.

Also, If we add support for newest version of crystal reports, can the older version still work too so we don't have to update all existing customers installs?

I have identified that from SP21 backward compatibility is broken by googling but not sure of what are available options to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the Visual Studio plugin?  If yes, which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @R.McMillan We installed the MSI in the machine and we reference the Crystal reports DLLs in our project. When the MSI version installed on the machine is 13.0.12 then the project works fine but as soon as we upgrade the Crystal report version to a newer version the code breaks.

Comment: It looks like SAP has made some changes to how different versions are compatible with each other since the last time I used Crystal Reports in Visual Studio and I need to brush up on it myself.  However, I did find [this link](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/10/30/upgrading-a-visual-studio-2008-2019-.net-project-with-the-latest-cr-.net-sdk-packages/?update=updated) that may be helpful.